# Represent nested keys as classes in java

Tags: java

I have a document that has simple and nested keys.

Simple keys look like this:

```
cass SimpleKey {
   String name;
   String val;
}
```

Nested keys like this:

```
cass NestedKey {
   String name;
   List<NestedKey> val;
}
```

So, a simple key consists only of `name` and `val`, a nested key of `name` and any number of simple keys or nested keys.

The problem I am having is that I need to put both nested and simple keys into the same lists.

Therefore I did `SimpleKey extends NestedKey` and, if needed, cast `NestedKey` into `SimpleKey`.

However, this feels really weird - a `SimpleKey` does not extend a `NestedKey`. What would be the best way to represent this?

I had a look at the Composite pattern, but I need to be able to iterate over lists of `NestedKey` instances (and `SimpleKey`) and access fields and if I give them a common interface or parent class, this would mean I need to cast the list elements every time I want to access the `name` and `val` fields, right? So even more casting that now.

**EDIT**

I need to turn this:

```
simplekey val
this.is.a.nested.key val
```

into this:

```
simple val
this
  is
   a
    nested
      key val (<-- looks like a simple key)
```

Comment: Your `NestedKey` class does not seem to have an end to it.  What I mean by this is, how does the tree of nested key children know how to end?  I almost feel like suggesting you make _everything_ a nested key, with the suggestion that a simple key is simply a nested key with no children.  But, I can't answer without knowing more about your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not quite sure what you mean by "how to end"? I am parsing a file which has a flat key structure, where keys are separated by dots if they are nested or just a "key"-"value" pair if they are simple. I need to parse the dot-separated key names and turn them into a nested key structure. But the leaf of a nested key always consists of a name-val-pair, like a SimpleKey does.

Comment: So could you make every key have a string value, which would be `null`, except for leaf keys, in which case the list would be `null`?

Comment: Can you implement a simple key as a nested key with a single element in the list? Without knowing why you need to distinguish between different key types, it's hard to recommend a particular approach. (However, a shared interface is probably be the way to go if you need to maintain a distinction.)

Comment: Okay, that would work... I am just not sure about using null... is that good class design/OOP? If so, then yeah, this would work.

Comment: @TedHopp I dont functionally need to distinguish between them, I just did it in the code.

Comment: If you don't need a distinction, don't code a distinction. :) Just make a single class and the code that uses it will probably end up simpler.

Comment: Why not have NestedKey and SimpleKey extend a BaseKey that only has a name member?

Comment: I think you should be more specific (please add to the question, not in comments) about the task you need to do: what are the inputs, what are the outputs? What are the data structures that use these keys? The edit doesn't explain much since we don't know what kind of a data structure this is.